# How to explain get_weight with autoencoder in keras?

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I built an autoencoder model of three layers with 9 5 9.
Input dim =9, encoder dim =5, output dim=9
When I get the model weights,

```
weight1=autoencoder.layers[1].get_weights()
weight2=autoencoder.layers[2].get_weights()
print(weight1)
[array([[ 0.0023533 , -0.02289476, -0.01658   ,  0.03487475, -0.38416424],
       [ 0.00594878,  0.01835718,  0.01768207,  0.04458401,  0.10922299],
       [ 0.03288281,  0.22234452,  0.04393397, -0.14807932,  0.04412287],
       [ 0.16347113,  0.02014653, -0.05967368, -0.09127634,  0.9797626 ],
       [-0.0901033 ,  0.1602385 , -0.16297013,  0.43326673, -0.2514738 ],
       [ 0.00272129, -0.00525797,  0.01420719, -0.04066049, -0.01261563],
       [ 0.40665478, -0.07740633, -0.02576585,  0.0406443 , -0.218632  ],
       [-0.00641229,  0.08050939, -0.02497054, -0.12399215,  0.10901988],
       [-0.14366671,  0.02168852,  0.19099002, -0.10509221, -0.4306924 ]],
      dtype=float32), array([-0.0133634 ,  0.14412224,  0.13419336, -0.32834613, -0.31566525],
      dtype=float32)]
```

There have two array in weight1.
I know the first array means but how to explain the second array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the layer contain two matrices, one for the actual weights and one for the **biases**?

There could be one bias value for each of the columns in your weight matrix, depending on how you built your model.